# Is there any way to reattach an 'orphaned' Windows installation?

Tags: mac, bootcamp, startup, partition, windows

I have a Windows installation in a partition on my hard drive. The problem is, it's not showing up when I startup holding alt.

I installed Windows through VirtualBox, linked to a physical partition on my hard drive. It all fully installed and boots in VirtualBox, but it doesn't show up on the boot drive selection.

I installed through Vbox because my Optical drive is broken, so I can't use the actual Windows installation disk I have. I tried creating a 'bootable' Windows installation USB key with Boot Camp Assistant, but when it actually came to installing Windows, it wouldn't work.

So yeah, is there a way to tell EFI that the Windows partition actually exists?

Comment: That's a good idea. Eventually, I just installed rEFInd, which detects the partition automatically.

Comment: I can think of lots of reasons why that should not have worked, but if it did for you, great.

Comment: Just curious, why should that not have worked?

Comment: Well, I suppose with all the different Mac models, you must have found a way to install on your model that I have not yet encountered. i would need more information to answer you question. For example, what model is you Mac? Did you do a EFI/GPT or BIOS/MBR install? Which version of Windows 7? Does all you hardware work after installing the Boot Camp Support Software?